# Block everything except some urls in IE 11 using GPO

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, whitelist, gpo

I want to whitelist some urls in IE , and block everything else 
How can this be achieved (using GPO), thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, GPO can't meet your requirements because the Internet Explorer Maintenance setting in IE11 GPO has been deprecated.

You could try to configure **proxy settings** using IE Administration Kit 11 or by deploying registries keys to achieve what you want. For more details, please refer to the following documents:

[Missing Internet Explorer Maintenance settings for Internet Explorer 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/missing-internet-explorer-maintenance-settings-for-ie11)

[Using Proxy Servers together with Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/use-proxy-servers-with-ie#use-group-policy)

Comment: Thanks a lot , I deployed some proxy HKCU reg keys here :
Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings   &     
Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel